# If $G$ is a group in which $(ab)^i = a^ib^i$ for two consecutive integers $i$, for all $a,b \in G$, can we conclude that $G$ is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Problem:

> If $G$ is a group in which $(ab)^i = a^ib^i$ for three consecutive integers $i$ for all $a,b \in G$, then $G$ is abelian. If we assume the relation $(ab)^i = a^ib^i$ for just two consecutive integers can we conclude that $G$ is abelian?

Thank all!

Comment: The assumption holds for $i=0$ and $i=1$ in any group. Perhaps you intended to assume that it holds for two consecutive positive integers?

Comment: Yes you are right, so the problem in Herstein's book is trivial. But it is slightly less trivial if you assume that the condition holds for two consecutive positive integers.

Comment: In my opinion, with this case we can't conclude that $G$ is abelian, because $(a.b)^0 = e$ does not implies $ba = e$ and $a.b = a.b$ does not implies $ab = ba$.

Comment: Yes exactly. What I am saying is that in every group $G$ and for all $a,b \in G$ we have $(ab)^0 = a^0b^0 = 1$, and $(ab)^1 = ab$. Since this is true in every group, we clearly cannot conclude that $G$ is abelian, . So your question is true but trivial (and the same applies to Herstein's question, so there is no need to feel bad about it).

Comment: I ask this quention for find an example to prove that isn't true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two consecutive integers is not enough to conclude that $G$ is abelian.

Let $G$ be any non-abelian group and $e$ the exponent of $G$ (so the least positive integer such that $g^e=1$ for all $g \in G$). Then $(ab)^e=1=a^eb^e$ and $(ab)^{e+1} = ab=a^{e+1}b^{e+1}$ for all $a,b \in G$.

Comment: You can also use any multiples of the exponent ; in particular, it's true for $e=0$ in *any* group.

Comment: As others have pointed out, this argument only works in groups of finite exponent.

Answer (score 4):

Three is enough.

First we have that 
$$
a^{i+2} b^{i+2} = (ab)^{i+2} = (ab)^{i+1} (ab) = a^{i+1} b^{i+1} ab,
$$
that is,
$$ a^{i+2} b^{i+2} = a^{i+1} b^{i+1} ab, $$
implying that 
$$ a b^{i+1} = b^{i+1} a,$$
meaning that $i+1$ powers commute with all elements.

Now,
$$
a^{i+2} b^{i+2} = (ab)^{i+2} = (ab)^{i} (ab)^2 = a^i b^i (ab)^2 = a^i b^i (ab)(ab) = a^i b^i ab ab ,
$$
that is,
$$ a^{i+2} b^{i+2} = a^i b^i a b a b, $$
from which it follows that 
$$ a^2 b^{i+1} = b^i a b a.$$

Reorder the terms on the LHS and conclude 
$$ b^{i+1} a^2 = b^i a b a, $$
so that 
$$ b a = ab, $$ 
as required.

Comment: That's not what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$$(ab)^iab=(ab)^{i+1}=a^{i+1}b^{i+1}=aa^ib^ib=a(ab)^ib$$

Right-cancelling with $b^{-1}$, we get:

$$(ab)^ia=a(ab)^i$$

By a similar argument (starting with $ab(ab)^i$), we have that $b$ commutes with $(ab)^i$. This will be true in any group where $g^i=e$ for all $g$. However, this is true in any finite group, Abelian or not, if we set $i=k|G|$ for any integer $k$, for example.

Comment: If we assume $G$ is any group (finite or infinite), then the statement isn't true, it's only true with the finite group with $i$ is an exponent of $G$.

Comment: Good point. I was clearly thinking of finite groups.