# Problem of Algebra Abstract by Herstein sec. 2.2 number 4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Problem 3

If $G$ is a group in which $(ab) ^i = a^i b^i$ for three consecutive integers $i$, prove that $G$ is abelian.

Show that the result of problem 3 would not always be true if the word “three“ were replaced by “two”. in other words, show that there is a group $G$ and consecutive numbers $i$, $i +1$ such that $G$ is not abelian but does have the property that

$$(ab) ^i = a^i b^i$$ and

$$(ab)^{i+1}  = a^{i+1} b^{i+1}$$

$\forall \, a, b \in G$

Comment: Second part: [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2466041/if-g-is-a-group-in-which-a-bi-ai-bi-for-two-consecutive-integers?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thank you 